# Отключить БД postgresql

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть несколько БД на сервере postgresql 9.4. Одна база находится в другом tablespace. Существует необходимость на время отмонтировать раздел, на котором располагается tablespace этой базы. Есть ли возможность каким-либо образом отключить эту БД для того, чтобы сервер баз данных postgresql продолжил нормально функционировать? БД не системная, обращений к ней не будет. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто отмонтировать раздел на "холодную" БД. Сервер баз данных стартует, ругаясь только на неполный стартовый пакет, но работает нормально. При попытке обращения к отключенной БД он говорит, что БД не существует. Примонтировать раздел обратно тоже надо на холодную. БД определилась сразу.